# Unable to Parse CSV delimited with only commas using spring batch

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-batch

Am getting IncorrectTokenCountException when try to parse CSV file from FlatFileItemReader.The CSV file is delimited only by commas and even linebreaks are commas.I want to extract 13 fields which are SYMBOL,SERIES,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,LAST,PREVCLOSE,TOTTRDQTY,TOTTRDVAL,TIMESTAMP,TOTALTRADES.

But it is reading an extra ',' from the input.
input=

> [20MICRONS,EQ,29.75,29.75,28.5,28.75,28.85,29,48937,1421432.2,04-DEC-2015,238,INE144J01027,]

Already answered questions do not seem to help me.How do i make sure that only first 13 tokens are considered as a single line.

Exception:

```
org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 2 in resource=[class path resource [cm04DEC2015bhav.csv]], input=[20MICRONS,EQ,29.75,29.75,28.5,28.75,28.85,29,48937,1421432.2,04-DEC-2015,238,INE144J01027,]
at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:183)
at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.read(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:155)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:114)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:108)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:395)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:131)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:267)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:253)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:137)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:152)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:131)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127)
at com.equities.batch.App.main(App.java:37)
Caused by:                   org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectTokenCountException: Incorrect number of tokens found in record: expected 13 actual 14
at org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.AbstractLineTokenizer.tokenize(AbstractLineTokenizer.java:124)
at    org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper.mapLine(DefaultLineMapper.java:43)
at          org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader     .java:180)
 ... 41 more
```

Sample CSV File contents :
SYMBOL,SERIES,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,LAST,PREVCLOSE,TOTTRDQTY,TOTTRDVAL,TIMESTAMP,TOTALTRADES,ISIN,20MICRONS,EQ,29.75,29.75,28.5,28.75,28.85,29,48937,1421432.2,04-DEC-2015,238,INE144J01027,3IINFOTECH,EQ,4.3,5.15,4,5.15,5.15,4.3,16790313,81105043.75,04-DEC-2015,5998,INE748C01020,3MINDIA,EQ,11279.05,11356.85,11115,11174.25,11150,11279.8,633,7096578.7,04-DEC-2015,212,INE470A01017,

```
Spring config file :
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

<import resource="../config/context.xml" />
<import resource="../config/database.xml" />

<bean id="report" class="com.equities.batch.Report" scope="prototype" />
<bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.equities.batch.CustomItemProcessor" />

<batch:job id="eodBatchJob" restartable="true">
  <batch:step id="step1">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="csvFileItemReader" writer="xmlItemWriter" 
                          processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="10">
        </batch:chunk>
    </batch:tasklet>
  </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="csvFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"   scope="step">
            <property name="linesToSkip" value="1"></property>

    <property name="resource" value="classpath:#{jobParameters['FILE']}" />

    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
        <property name="lineTokenizer">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                <property name="delimiter">
                    <util:constant
                        static-field="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_COMMA" />
                    </property>
                <property name="names" value="SYMBOL,SERIES,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,LAST,PREVCLOSE,TOTTRDQTY,TOTTRDVAL,TIMESTAMP,TOTALTRADES,ISIN" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="fieldSetMapper">
            <bean class="com.equities.batch.ReportFieldSetMapper" />

             <!-- if no data type conversion, use BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper to map by name
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="report" />
            </bean>
             -->
        </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:xml/outputs/report.xml" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="reportMarshaller" />
    <property name="rootTagName" value="report" />
</bean>

<bean id="reportMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
   <property name="classesToBeBound">
    <list>
        <value>com.equities.batch.Report</value>
    </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Mapper Class :

```
package com.equities.batch;



import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;


public class ReportFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<Report>{

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.FieldSetMapper#mapFieldSet(org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FieldSet)
 */
public Report mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {

    Report report =new Report();
    System.out.println("Count"+fieldSet.getFieldCount());
    report.setSymbol(fieldSet.readString(0));
    report.setSeries(fieldSet.readString(1));
    report.setOpenPrice(fieldSet.readBigDecimal(2));
    report.setHighPrice(fieldSet.readBigDecimal(3));
    report.setLowPrice(fieldSet.readBigDecimal(4));
    report.setClosePrice(fieldSet.readBigDecimal(5));
    report.setLastTradedPrice(fieldSet.readBigDecimal(6));
    report.setPrevClosePrice(fieldSet.readBigDecimal(7));
    report.setTotalTradedQty(fieldSet.readInt(8));
    report.setTotalTradedValue(fieldSet.readBigDecimal(9));

    String date=fieldSet.readString(10);
    System.out.println("DATE"+date);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");

    try {
        System.out.println("DATE formatted"+formatter.parse(date));

        report.setDate(formatter.parse(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    report.setTotalTrades(fieldSet.readInt(11));
    report.setISIN(fieldSet.readString(12));



    return report;
}
```

}

Comment: "even linebreaks are commas" ? This is not a good idea, put real line breaks.

Comment: This Csv is downloaded dynamically from a URL , hence am not modifying it to add line breaks ,am just reading as is.

Comment: Then , how do you or spring batch make the difference between field separator and line separator ? There is no way to do that .

Comment: Oh Berger do you mean to say that I cannot process this kinda CSV using spring batch at all...?  I haven't written any extra code to differentiate field and line since both are same in this case ie comma

Comment: You could write a custom reader, that reads the entire line into memory in it's init() method and then returns a line by counting the number of comma's that constitute a line.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the suggestions but the problem was solved when i added an extra ',' in the names property.

```
<bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                <property name="delimiter">
                    <util:constant
                        static-field="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_COMMA" />
                    </property>
                <property name="names" value="SYMBOL,SERIES,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,LAST,PREVCLOSE,TOTTRDQTY,TOTTRDVAL,TIMESTAMP,TOTALTRADES,ISIN," />
            </bean>
```